# Ошибка синтаксиса в ALTER SEQUENCE при написании триггерной функции

Tags: sql, postgresql, функции, триггер

Такая проблема пишу триггер что при удалении sequence откатывался на последнее максимальное значение id

```
DECLARE
  max_id integer;
BEGIN
 SELECT MAX (id) INTO max_id FROM table;
 ALTER SEQUENCE table_id_seq RESTART WITH max_id;
 RETURN NEW;
END
```

Подчеркивает последний max_id говорит ошибка синтаксиса 42601
Гугл меня не понял...

Comment: Наверняка переменную нельзя ставить в alter. кроме того alter вообще не стоит вызывать из триггера, ибо он транзакционно не безопасен. запись может не удалится, а alter отработает. Кроме того - _никогда_ не уменьшайте значение секвенса. Не надо пытаться экономить id, это плохо заканчивается в 9 случаев из 10 и не решает ни каких проблем

Comment: select max(id) кстати то же не безопасен, особенно с секвенсами. какая то другая транзакция в это время уже может получить значение из секвенса, после этого отработает max(id) получит то что в таблице, а вслед за этим отработает insert с новым id который превышает только что полученный max

Comment: Ну впринципи совет дельный  делаю это по прихоти и просто не понял почему не выходит -_-

Comment: DDL операции обычно не позволяют использовать в себе никакие переменные, их синтаксический анализатор ожидает видеть константы. А такие прихоти стоит попробовать решить другим путем.